Can jQuery Access DOM Elements Updated by React?
I'm attempting to access the class "wpgmp-map-data-container" from the updated DOM, but it consistently returns 0, despite the class being present in the DOM..
edit.js
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const [mapMarkupState, setMapMarkupState] = useState("");

    const fetchMapMarkup = async (id) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                `${siteurl}/wp-json/wpgmp/${version}/markup/${id}`,
            );
            const markupData = await response.json();
            setMapMarkupState(markupData.map_markup);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching map markup:", error);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMapMarkup(id);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(mapMarkupState ){
            wpgmpInitMap();
        }
    }, [mapMarkupState]);

    return (
        <>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: mapMarkupState }} />
        </>
    );
}

The jQuery code is contained within maps.js and is globally accessible.
when querying for the .wpgmp-map-data-container class using jQuery, I expected the length to be 1
function wpgmpInitMap() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        console.log( 'Length = ',$(".wpgmp-map-data-container").length );

    });
}


This is a pure guess, because I don't fully understand your code: You're executing fetchMapMarkup() asynchronously, so the main thread directly continues to excute wpgmpInitMap(), and the JQuery code there is executed before the .wpgmp-map-data-container class is added to the DOM by fetchMapMarkup() because it has to wait for the fetch to complete.

How can I ensure that my DOM updates first, and then the wpgmpInitMap() function is called, so that the class .wpgmp-map-data-container class has a length of 1?

You could try and call wpgmpInitMap() from within fetchMapMarkup() after all the waiting is done and the DOM set.

I've already attempted to call wpgmpInitMap() from within fetchMapMarkup() after waiting for the DOM to be set, but the length still returns 0.
const markupData = await response.json();
setMapMarkupState(markupData.map_markup);
if(mapMarkupState){
wpgmpInitMap();
}

As I said, I don't fully understand your code, so I'm not the best person to advice you on this. I would put wpgmpInitMap(); directly after the setMapMarkupState(markupData.map_markup); line, which I assume updates the DOM, without any if () condition. Does anybody else have any ideas?
